# existence of a linear operator which extends linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $W$ is finite dimensional and $T_1,T_2 \in L(V,W)$. Prove that null $T_1 \subset$ null $T_2$ if and only if there exists $S \in L(W,W)$ such that $T_2=ST_1$

I proved that if there exists $S \in L(W,W)$ such that $T_2=ST_1$ then null $T_1 \subset$ null $T_2$. However, I have no idea how to prove the existence of such $S$. I tried to construct such $S$ but failed. Can anyone give me any hint?

This is a problem in the new Linear Algebra Done Right. A result of preceding exercise (proved) may be useful: Suppose $U$ and $V$ are finite dimensional vector spaces and $S \in L(V,W)$ and $T \in L(U,V)$, then dim null$ST \leq$ dim null$S$ + dim null$T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Begin with a basis $(v_1,\dots,v_j)$ of null $T_1$.  Extend this to a basis $(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ of null $T_2$.  Extend that to a basis $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ of $V$.

Define your map so that it takes the vectors $T_1v_{j+1},\dots,T_1 v_k$ to $0$ and $T_1 v_{k+1},\dots,T_1 v_{n}$ to $T_2 v_{k+1},\dots,T_2 v_{n}$.

Comment: Cool. I also tried to extend the basis of null space but I gave up.

Comment: Glad it works for you.  If you know about quotient spaces, there's a quicker approach not involving bases.